# conditional form validation using jquery.validate.js plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

Can anyone tell me how to write a rule that validates if neither one radio button option nor the (optinal) textfield is chosen/filled by a user? The rule should only give a message if no checkbox option `#myradiogroup` is chosen AND the textfield `#email2` is empty.

My form code:

```
<form name="my" id="myForm" action="" method="post">

<input type="radio" name="myradiogroup" id="myradiogroup" value="option 1" /> option 1
<input type="radio" name="myradiogroup" id="myradiogroup" value="option 2" /> option 2

<label for="emailNew4use">this is an optional field:</label>
<input type="text" name="email2" id="email2" />

<input type="submit" value="send">

</form>
```

Comment: it would have been really helpful if you had been much clearer in what you were expecting as an answer

Comment: You should also show your `.validate()` code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `required` parameter in jQuery Validate can take a function.

```
$('#myForm').validate({
    rules: {
        email2: {
            required: function(element) {
                if ($('[name="myradiogroup"]:checked').length) {
                    return false;
                } else {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        },
        myradiogroup: {
            required: function(element) {
                if ($('#email2').val()) {
                    return false;
                } else {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

---

Here's a condensed version from [Sparky](https://stackoverflow.com/users/594235/sparky)

```
$('#myForm').validate({
    rules: {
        email2: {
            required: function(element) {
                return !$('[name="myradiogroup"]:checked').length;
            }
        },
        myradiogroup: {
            required: function(element) {
                return !$('#email2').val();
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: You should be able to condense it all down by replacing the entire if/else.  Example:  `return !($('[name="myradiogroup"]:checked').length);`

Comment: @Sparky excellent point! I think it can be made even shorter with dependency strings (you can provide a selector to match) but I can't get that to work... and I have real work to do at the office today, so I'll leave it at that. :)

Comment: I've had mixed results using the `depends` method.

Answer (score -2):

maybe can this:

```
$('#myForm').submit(function() {
    if($('input:radio').val() == '' || $('#email2').val() == '') {
        preventDefault();
        // show error
    }
}
```

Comment: Is'nt michbeck looking for jquery validation?